# .jar won't run when launched from C# program

Tags: c#, java

I'm using C# to develop some programs for Kinect. C# doesn't have anything as good as Java's Robot for simulating Keystrokes or Mouse movements, so I'm using Java for that. At the moment, I'm creating .jar files and trying to run them from the C# application (although I'm suspicious that there's a better way to do it). The way I do this is by putting this line in my C# code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", java -jar C:\\Users\\Me\\RobotProgram.jar");
```

This works fine in a small, basic C# application:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/c java -jar C:\\Users\\Me\\RobotProgram.jar");
        }
    }
}
```

But when it's in a more complex program that uses the Kinect camera, it won't work. The console flashes up saying "Error occurred during initialization of VM java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object".

Comment: Looks like Java standard libraries are not loaded correctly. Try to add that to the Java interpreter switches as well.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean when you say add that to the Java interpreter switches? Add what?

Answer (score 0):

The Java project may be looking for required  files in the working directory. Try setting the working directory before launching.

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory("C:\\Users\\Me");
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/c java -jar C:\\Users\\Me\\RobotProgram.jar");
```

Comment: The files the VM is looking for are the basic classes (e.g. java.lang.Object, see error message) -- changing to the working directory won't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify the application's entry point.

Here's a simple explanation: https://samindaw.wordpress.com/2008/11/04/specifying-the-main-class-to-run-in-a-jar-file-from-command-line/

Comment: He says it's working in a smaller environment, so this does not seem to be the problem

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your JAVA_HOME environmental variable set up properly in the environment where the complex program is running?

The error points to an empty/wrong JAVA_HOME as even the base classes are not found

Comment: I'm not sure what this means. My standard Java environment variables are set up properly, but I'm not sure I understand what you're saying about being set up 'in the environment where the complex program is running'. What should I do to check this?

Comment: You could execute a command like `echo %JAVA_HOME% > <somefile>` from your application (where `<somefile>` is a path to a file where you capture the output of the `echo` command -- `>` is a redirection operator, taking standard output and redirecting it to a file) -- just like you do with the `java` command.  Then compare the content of that file with what you expect to see as the value of the environment variable `JAVA_HOME`

Comment: Sorry if I'm being slow, I tried that and it just printed "%JAVA_HOME%" to the text file.

Comment: That means the variable is not set (try: `echo %PATH%` and `echo %A%` from a command line, and see the difference in behavior -- assuming env. var. `A` is not set)  You need to make sure the variable is set in that environment, then it should work just like in the simpler example

Comment: Ok, I see. The only thing I don't know how to do now is work out which environment the C# program is running in - it isn't just a matter of changing directory, because if I manually change directory to one that usually works on the command prompt produced by the C# program, it still gives the same error.

Comment: How do you start your C# program?

Comment: I'm starting it through visual C# 2010.

Comment: That is strange.  VS should have access to your environmental variables.  Does it still do the same if you restart VS?  Also, something in your more complex program could reset the env.variables...  I'm affraid I will not be able to help you further on this.  As a last resort, you can specify the classpath on the java command line, but note that hard-coding the path in your program will make it non-portable and very brittle (e.g. if you install java in a different directory later on)

Comment: Ok, I'll give that stuff a go, if only just to find out what's sorting the problem. I'll update this thread/question if I fix it or find a workaround. Thanks very much for the help!

Comment: Still no luck on this. However, there is some new information on the problem. I've tried a couple of other solutions, like IKVM and JRuby. But then I get the error 'jruby is not recognised as an internal command, operable program or batch file.' (same with ikvm), despite the fact that they are added to the Path, and both work fine from the normal command line. I've also discovered that it isn't something specific to my project, except that it's a WPF application. Even a very simple wpf application can replicate the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems like your env.variables don't carry over to the WPF app properly (or they get overwritten somewhere).  I'm just stabbing in the dark here, but maybe the difference is user context: can you tell me what your PATH, JAVA_HOME and CLASSPATH settings are for System (Control Panel->System->Advanced system settings->Environment Variables...->System variables) and the user (Control Panel->System->Advanced system settings->Environment Variables...->User variables for <username>)?

Comment: I used the SET command to try and get everything, and I've put it [here](http://pastebin.com/7xpHS5A8). Is that the right stuff?

Comment: The output you posted is a mix of the two settings (System and User), but might still be usable.  Can you output the result of `SET` and paste that too?  Run "set > wpf_env.txt" from your C# app (like you did with java and echo earlier) and paste the contents of wpf_env.txt to pastebin.com.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ECDsqQX0 . I think only jre6 is listed in the path, but I get the same error from jars made with jre6 and jre7.

Comment: A few things are deifintely different (e.g. JAVA_HOME is not set in the second case), so the fact that is works from your user account is meaningless here.  I suspect you have JAVA_HOME set on your User settings, not on the System settings and NS uses the System settings -- try copying the JAVA_HOME definition to the System settings (see how to get there in my previous posts)

Comment: I've added it as a system variable (I just made the variable name "JAVA_HOME" and the value "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7" but it doesn't seem to write that value to the wpf_env.txt file. Is that not the correct way to add a system variable?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9603/discussion-between-attila-and-user1002973)